How can I write this the right way?
I want this exact same layout (or something similar):

I have no idea how to make it the right way. I have this error "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)" (I have no idea what it means but I guess it has to do with the successive \hfill)
\section{Dados utilizados para os cálculos da Torção}
$R=\SI{0.01}{\meter} \hfill t=\SI{0.0012}{\meter} \hfill r=\SI{0.0088}{\meter} \hfill b=\SI{0.18}{\meter}$\\\\
$T = P \hspace*{0.1cm} \cdot \hspace*{0.1cm}  b$\hfill $E= \SI{70}{\giga\pascal}$\hfill $\nu=0.3$ \hfill $\alpha=\SI{45}{\degree}$
\\\\
$J=\frac{\pi}{2}\hspace*{0.1cm} \cdot \hspace*{0.1cm} (R^4-r^4)\implies J= \SI{6.29e-9}{\meter^4}$\hfill
$\tau_{xy}=\frac{T\hspace*{0.1cm} \cdot \hspace*{0.1cm} R}{J}$ \hfill $\gamma_{xy}=2\hspace*{0.1cm} \cdot \hspace*{0.1cm} \varepsilon_{zz}$ \vspace{1em}
 
\begin{align*}
    &\varepsilon_{\alpha}=  \cancel{\varepsilon_{xx}\hspace*{0.1cm} \cdot \hspace*{0.1cm} \cos^2(\alpha)}\hspace*{0.1cm} + \hspace*{0.1cm}\cancel{\varepsilon_{zz}\hspace*{0.1cm} \cdot \hspace*{0.1cm} \cos^2(\alpha)}\hspace*{0.1cm} + \hspace*{0.1cm}\gamma_{xz}\hspace*{0.1cm} \cdot \hspace*{0.1cm} \sin(\alpha)\hspace*{0.1cm} \cdot \hspace*{0.1cm} \cos(\alpha) \iff\\
&\varepsilon_{\alpha}=2\hspace*{0.1cm} \cdot \hspace*{0.1cm} \varepsilon_{xy}\hspace*{0.1cm} \cdot \hspace*{0.1cm} \sin^2(\SI{45}{\degree}) \iff \varepsilon_{\alpha}=\varepsilon_{xy}
\end{align*}

\[
\varepsilon_{xy}=\frac{1+\nu}{E}\hspace*{0.1cm} \cdot \hspace*{0.1cm} \tau_{xy}
\]


This what I have written.
Thanks in advance.

Please can you make your code snippet compilable? We need to be able to reproduce your situation. That message is not an error but "only" a warning. I don't mean it doesn't matter, but there's a difference between that and an error which stops compilation. The warning is almost certainly due to your use of \\\\ . Never end a line with \\  unless you are in a special environment such as a tabular. Especially don't do it before a paragraph. And doubly especially don't do it twice. Use e.g. \bigskip if you want to add space manually, but you shouldn't generally need to do this at all.

@Werner Is it useful to migrate the question from SO to TeX.se if it was already cross-posted here?
